# html2canvas screenshot of external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html2canvas

I don't have even any idea how to do this and the documentation of html2canvas is not really helpful at this part.

I'm able to make a screenshot of my html with this little piece of code:

```
target = $('#myDiv');
        html2canvas( target, {
        onrendered: function( canvas ) {
            /* canvas is the actual canvas element, 
               to append it to the page call for example 
             */
               document.body.appendChild( canvas );
            }
        })
```

but i want to be able to pass an url and make a screenshot of this page. Like they do in their example page on: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

If anyone could give me a hint how to get started with that, I would be really glad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, for security reasons, load just any external URL.  That's why, as they described on the page you linked to, you need to set up a separate server-side script that fetches the page.  You then use that script, either directly or via AJAX, to provide the input for html2canvas.

Comment: Like in php i would call file_get_contents() to get the page and then echo it and use it in the ajax-success-callback? Did i get this right?

Comment: I don't remember the PHP offhand, sorry.

Comment: hm, okay, could you at least tell me how the call for html2canvas would look like: I have now something like:

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "ajax.php",
    data: { action: 'getPageContent', url: 'http://google.de' } 
  }).done(function(html) {
   // How to use it from here?
  });

Comment: I don't know; it depends on how you've created your script, but that looks roughly correct.  I would take a look through the jQuery AJAX docs.